# If an international flight is turned around mid-air, do the passengers have to pass the immigration and customs upon arrival?

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, international-travel

I read on https://amp.cnn.com/cnn/2021/12/28/business/delta-shanghai-flight-turned-back-covid/index.html:

> Delta turned flight around mid-air, saying China's new Covid cleaning rules are unworkable.

If an international flight is turned around mid-air, do the passengers  have to pass the immigration and customs upon arrival at their original departure airport? If the answer is country-dependent. I'm mostly interested in the United States.

Comment: In The case if Schengen, departure stamps can be cancelled (double bar in one corner). We’ve seen cases here of such cancelled stamps at land borders. For air departures, I suppose the initial situation is that you are just back in the international departures area, and then depending on the situation they may readout your by cancelling the exit stamp.

Comment: And if you do pass through customs, what happens if you bought duty-free booze and cigarettes in quantities that were OK at your destination but exceed the allowances for the country you were departing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> do the passengers have to pass the immigration

Generally yes. Once you are through exit controls, you are out of the country, and you need to clear immigration again to return.

Example: I was in China waiting for our plane to depart at the international gate. The flight was cancelled and they needed to put up passengers for the night. That required full re-entry into China and the Chinese government set up a processing line for those people who needed another short term Visa (since their single or double use Visa was invalidated at departure). Apparently that happens often enough that they have staff for this on hand. Happened a few times to me too.

It's a bit murkier for the US since there are no exit controls and the domestic departure area is no different from the international one. Technically they could decide either way. I'm not aware of any specific regulations for this case, so chances are, it's up to the local shift leader to decide how to handle this.

**UPDATE** based on an answer from law stack exchange https://law.stackexchange.com/a/76628/15309

From https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2019-Sep/CBP-Memo-Carriers-Flight-Diversion-20190516-seal-508.pdf

> Passengers and crew on flights departing the United States for foreign destinations that make an unscheduled stop in the United States due to any emergency, including but not limited to fuel related, weather-related, mechanical-related, illness on board, or other emergency reason, generally are not be processed by CBP, but treated as a domestic arrival.

So the guidelines say that they passengers don't have to pass through immigration but whether the local CBP manager would follow the guidelines is anyone's guess.

Comment: Is there some reason why you think that the local CBP would ignore the guidelines and just make it up on the spot?

Comment: @djr I suppose that discretion exists to allow for unexpected situations.  If the guidelines say "generally," that implies that there are exceptions.  The local CBP might require inspection without ignoring the guidelines.

Comment: @djr: What normally happens is that CBP/USCIS use the flight's APIS information to update every (non-US citizen) passenger's I-94 to account for the departure. I imagine that, in the event of an unscheduled landing, this operation needs to be cancelled or reversed. If, due to some bizarre problem, CBP/USCIS were unable to do that, then they might decide to re-process everybody and reissue new I-94s. But that would be pretty unusual, I think. There might also be weird situations where someone with asylum status or a T visa tries to fly to their home country, and has to have their visa revoked.

Comment: Now I read some accounts on Chinese social media, Apparently in this particular case some customs processing was done and parole procedures were applied for some passengers. Perhaps it was too far away or too long a time has passed when it turned back.

Comment: @djr I have every reason to believe this. I have certainly seen CBP officers making stuff up on the fly just because they feel like it. Occasionally that became outright abusive and blatantly illegal. CBP has a lot of discretionary power and some individuals get a kick out of  exercising those.